# How to set index in pandas when the columns are a multiindex with empty string , without PerformanceWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data -

```
       a        b        c      
0 dqu  x  y  z  x  y  z  x  y  z
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

Which has columns:

```
MultiIndex([(' ', 'dqu'),
            ('a',   'x'),
            (' ',   'y'),
            (' ',   'z'),
            ('b',   'x'),
            (' ',   'y'),
            (' ',   'z'),
            ('c',   'x'),
            (' ',   'y'),
            (' ',   'z')],
           )
```

I want to set the index as follows:

```
df.set_index((" ", "dqu"))
```

but I get the following warning:

```
PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this when I have columns like this though.